# Birt Report No active server found

Tags: spagobi, birt-deapi

I am starting with spagobi framework and spagobi studio.I used SpagoBI studio to create BIRT report.when I try to deploy the report on the SpagoBI server this error message appears:

[image]

the log file :

```
2017-05-10 ERROR it.eng.spagobi.studio.core.wizards.deployWizard.SpagoBIDeployWizardFormPage.createControl:136 - No active server found
it.eng.spagobi.studio.utils.exceptions.NoActiveServerException: null
    at it.eng.spagobi.studio.utils.services.ProxyHandler.<init>(ProxyHandler.java:45) ~[it.eng.spagobi.studio.utils_5.2.0.jar:na]
    at it.eng.spagobi.studio.utils.services.SpagoBIServerObjectsFactory.<init>(SpagoBIServerObjectsFactory.java:37) ~[it.eng.spagobi.studio.utils_5.2.0.jar:na]
    at it.eng.spagobi.studio.core.wizards.deployWizard.SpagoBIDeployWizardFormPage.createControl(SpagoBIDeployWizardFormPage.java:130) ~[it.eng.spagobi.studio.core_5.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:178) [org.eclipse.jface_3.10.2.v20141021-1035.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:759) [org.eclipse.jface_3.10.2.v20141021-1035.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:622) [org.eclipse.jface_3.10.2.v20141021-1035.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:435) [org.eclipse.jface_3.10.2.v20141021-1035.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1101) [org.eclipse.jface_3.10.2.v20141021-1035.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797) [org.eclipse.jface_3.10.2.v20141021-1035.jar:na]
    at it.eng.spagobi.studio.core.services.template.DeployTemplateService.doAutomaticDeploy(DeployTemplateService.java:255) [it.eng.spagobi.studio.core_5.2.0.jar:na]
    at it.eng.spagobi.studio.core.views.actionProvider.ResourceNavigatorActionProvider$10.run(ResourceNavigatorActionProvider.java:400) [it.eng.spagobi.studio.core_5.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519) [org.eclipse.jface_3.10.2.v20141021-1035.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595) [org.eclipse.jface_3.10.2.v20141021-1035.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511) [org.eclipse.jface_3.10.2.v20141021-1035.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420) [org.eclipse.jface_3.10.2.v20141021-1035.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84) [org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353) [org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061) [org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172) [org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761) [org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151) [org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.12.100.v20141126-1150.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332) [org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.4.1.v20140210-1835.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032) [org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.12.100.v20141126-1150.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148) [org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.2.2.v20141212-1259.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636) [org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.106.2.v20150204-1030.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332) [org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.4.1.v20140210-1835.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579) [org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.106.2.v20150204-1030.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150) [org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.106.2.v20150204-1030.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135) [org.eclipse.ui.ide.application_1.0.501.v20141111-1238.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196) [org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.200.v20130910-1609.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648) [org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603) [org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465) [org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar:na]
```

Anyone knows what is the problem??

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you installed SpagoBI server from the link http://forge.ow2.org/project/showfiles.php?group_id=204

Go to the project --> server ---> add a new server --- give the url of the link
 Username **biadmin**, password **biadmin** which is default.

Or if you added the spagoBI server mark it as active and save.

Answer (score 0):

There may be issue with Active server Configuration
url , user name , password etc
or the server may not be accessible from your system.

Instead of deploying document from SpagoBI Studio ,
better you login to spagobi server - with admin right and then browse template, 
attach the .rptdesign file

From studio you can get path of file by right clicking on the report and see properties.